# restoring error in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am a beginner with tensorflow and I was tinkering around with convnet for image recognition.However after I save my model I am getting an error while restoring it.

this is my tensor graph components ->

```
Y_train = to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=4)
Y_test = to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=4)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 64,64,3))
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 4))

w1 = tf.get_variable("w1", [4,4,3,8], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 0))
w2 = tf.get_variable("w2", [2,2,8,16], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 0))


Z1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X,w1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)
P1 = tf.nn.max_pool(A1, ksize = [1,8,8,1], strides = [1,8,8,1], padding = 'SAME')
Z2 = tf.nn.conv2d(P1,w2, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)
P2 = tf.nn.max_pool(A2, ksize = [1,4,4,1], strides = [1,4,4,1], padding = 'SAME')
P2 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(P2) 
Z3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(P2,4,activation_fn=None)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = Z3, labels = Y))


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.004).minimize(cost)
```

this is a basic convnet which i have successfully trained and tested.
However the problem I am facing is that after all the epochs have been completed for training, How do I save this model such that I can use it again in some file say predict.py where in I can just import it and make predictions

So i read some blogs on save and restore and did that but then I was getting the below mention error

> Attempting to use uninitialized value fully_connected/biases   [[Node:
>   fully_connected/biases/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

so given the convnet what should I do to use that model ? can someone provide working code for both the model file and predict file.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry for the incovenience, I have modified the question. The thing is I am  not even able to understand where exactly is the problem so I have even listed what I actually intend to do.

Comment: http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/[[link]   this is what i tried

Comment: Try to use `tf.global_variables_initializer()`.